# Supervisor package fails starting processes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I have installed `Supervisor` package for Ubuntu as someone recommended me here on serverfault to keep all my processes always alive.

But after two days of using it I saw by `supervisorctl` command: 4 processes of 10 has fatal error and not running.

```
...
sync   FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

I did the restart of all processes and they have been restored successfully. So why `Supervisor` didn't did that? How to set the permanent restoring of broken processes? 
Or what should I use to keep trying restore processes all the time without any timeout even if the process will be failing all the time? Because Database connection can be restored even after 8 hours, so it should be trying to reach the database without quiting all the time.

Comment: supervisor is only included for backward compatibility. You should use systemd on modern Linux systems. But of course neither of them will help if your application refuses to start. You should fix that problem first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why Supervisor didn't did that?

Supervisor did try to restart your processes, but they exited too quickly so it gave up after trying a configured number of times.

> How to set the permanent restoring of broken processes?

You can increase `startretries` value from default 3 to a higher number, so that supervisor doesn't give up too quickly. But first, you should inspect the logs of the process you are trying to restart and check why it failed to start these default three times.

> Or what should I use to keep trying restore processes all the time without any timeout even if the process will be failing all the time?

Don't do that - fix whatever it is that is preventing the process from running properly. Mindless restarting won't lead you anywhere. If you really need such behaviour (which is doubtful), explore systemd services.

Comment: Of course systemd will also give up after a while if the application fails to start.

Comment: But the systemd can be configured to retry indefinitely, while AFAIK supervisior can't.